# How do I use the MinGW compiler from the command line on Windows?

Tags: c++, c, windows, gcc, mingw

I have installed the Bloodshed [Dev-C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dev-C%2B%2B) compiler on my Windows 7 machine. Now how can I compile from the command line?

Answer (score 4):

#### File main.cpp:

```
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling:

```
g++ -Wall main.cpp -o main
```

The `bin` folder from MinGW has to be in the path environment variables, and for g++ there are lots of documentation on how to use it. As far as I know, there is not a difference from g++/MinGW and g++ from Linux, so any Linux tutorial will also work on Windows.

Comment: That is right. The path environment variable has to be updated. Its not done during installation.